# Make diff with IntelliJ more user friendly

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, diff, jetbrains-ide

I am using IntelliJ with the "compare with file..." function, which is very useful. Unfortunately, it seems to lack fundamentals commands in the right-click menu, like copy-paste and comment/uncomment line

[image]

In the merge situation, this is even worse.

Settings doesn't helps

[image]

How can I solve the situation and make this window more usable, without being forced for hotkeys/edit sources functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this functionalities to be introduced in IntelliJ without workarounds, please upvote this [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265709).